# Run As Ant Build Error

Tags: database, eclipse, ant

I'm working on a project on database development in eclipse. When I try to run the program, it only gives me the option to run as an Ant Build. When I choose Ant Build, I get a 'Build Failed Error', because an Ant File was not found. Do I need an Ant File to run a database program? If not, how can I run my program without it? I saw a similar question on another post, but the solutions I saw suggested that their program was probably missing a main method. My program has a main method, with a connection to the database in it. How can I get my program to run? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this a java program?  You should select Run As Java App, not ant build.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, this is a Java program. Run As is only giving me the Ant Build Option. How would I go about running it as a Java App?

Comment: You should see something like the pic below from File/Run As.  ![Run as Java App][1].  If not, then I am not sure what is wrong.  


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ux8wq.png

Comment: Can you zip up your project and send to me if it is a small prototype?